# **Not loading data on the page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to get information from one page and display it on the screen.

Before going to the data page, on the previous page, I have a ListviewBuilder that needs to be clicked.
**When the click is done, **two things happen****.

*First*, the page is Navigated to a **loading page**.
And *after Navigate*, **the method of getting data from Jason is executed**, which is called getDeiscriptionData.

Now, in getDeiscriptionData method, **after taking the data and pouring them into the data model**, the page will be changed to another page, and that is the same page where the information is supposed to be displayed.
But when Navigate is done, it seems that the values **​​return null**, and as a result, the default value that I put in **??'null'** is displayed, and I  **HotReload** *it once so that the original data appears on the page.*

> I need index number of ListView.builder to use in getDeiscriptionData method.
>
> I do not use state management.
>
> Do you have a solution?

**onTap in the ListView:**

```
  onTap: () async {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => testSplashScreen(),
            ),
          );
          getDeiscriptionData(context, index);
        },
```

**The method of getting data and navigating:**

```
Future<void> getDeiscriptionData(context, int onIndex) async {
  var responce = await Dio()
      .get('*******/${onIndex + 1}'.toString());

  var jsonMapObject = responce.data;
  var movieDiscription = MovieDiscription.fromMapJson(jsonMapObject);

  await Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => DescriptionPage(descriptions: movieDiscription),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: There are multiple technical flaws in how you are executing a loading screen and then again pushing a new screen. I will not go into that. What you can do is, check if responce in getDeiscriptionData function is not null and only if it is not null add the json to your movieDiscription and then use it to push a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why data loads after hot reload, you pushes screen first and then fetch for data and screen is loaded before data feches, if you want load screen with two scenario' if data is null and data not null ' you can simply await your getDeiscriptionData function before pushes new screen and then open.But i recomanded use getDeiscriptionData in new screens init state(pass parameters to new screen for getDeiscriptionData if you need) and use Future builder for pages body then accordingly to response you have your pages data,but if you want only when data is not null then you can do it with
'Md. Kamrul Amin's' commented way